# Admob: from lot of activity to inactive

Tags: admob, status

I have an Android app with admob ads. This app is very popular and has been online for more than 3 months now. 
From one day to another, five days ago the admob status became Inactive...it shows: "AdMob has never received an ad request for your site."
This app gave me US$80 a day, and now it went down to zero. I tried to contact admob through different ways (support form, emails, different languages) and I don't get any answer. 
I received no notification neither.

As you might expect, I'm VERY disappointed with Admob, and really don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Just the same happened to me... I think it's an admob error

Comment: Perroloco, solucionaste el problema ? Me pasa lo mismo, y al intentar contactar no me solucionan nada, me remiten a la típica ayuda de la aplicación nueva sin request.

Comment: @Fisher , el problema no lo pude solucionar. Los de AdMob me respondieron con plantillas prehechas que no ayudaban en absoluto. Intent'e cambiarme a FoxMob pero al final opté por crear otra app en admob y cambiar el api key... Esto significó perder un montón de clientes, pero ya se está recuperando con la actualización.
Si quieres, puedes mirar en mi blog, technozombies.net para mas información de lo ocurrido. También puedes comentar ahi tu situación así vamos actualizando las cosas que van pasando. Un saludo y espero que se solucione el problema!

Comment: Es lamentable ... En mi app tengo mas de 5000 request diarios, y sigue inactiva, ya ni me contestan al preguntar que coño ocurre. Un saludo

Comment: pero sigues con el problema? no esperes a que te contesten...no solucionar'an nada. Cambia el ad-key por uno nuevo...es lo que te recomiendo

Comment: Same happened to me ..... Better to use English i.e. every one can understand it ..... :(